# send activation email django-registration (Amazon SES)

Tags: python, django, django-registration

How to send activation email with username by using `django-registration`.I've configured `Amazon SES` on server.

Here is my settings

```
AWSAccessKeyId='my_key'
AWSSecretKey='my_key'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend`
```

When User trying to register. They get following error message. Will you please help me ? Thank you

```
NoAuthHandlerFound at /accounts/register/
No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV3Handler'] Check               your credentials
```

I'm doing something wrong? please help

## Latest UPDATE

```
'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV3Handler'] Check your credentials
```

## OLD UPDATE

I've made some changes in `settings.py`

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='my_key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='my_key'
```

Now I'm getting following error.

```
    BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MessageRejected</Code>
    <Message>Email address is not verified.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>37ceac2e-3861-11e1-acd0-19854590b66c</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to verify the email address that you are sending the emails from before amazon will accept the emails.

From the [Amazon SES page](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/):

> **Verify Email Addresses**: Before you can send email via Amazon SES, you need to verify that you own the address from which you’ll be sending email. To start the verification process, visit the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console).

Before you check whether django-registration can send emails, make sure that sending emails works from the shell

```
./manage.py shell
from django.core.mail import send_mail

verified_address = "from@example.com"
send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', verified_address,
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Any error messages might give you a clue what to try next. If `send_mail` works, then django registration is probably using the wrong address.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this command. `python manage.py ses_email_address -l`. And its displaying list of `verified emails`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what else to suggest. Hope you get it working.

Comment: What did you do to get it working? You can add your own answer and mark it as accepted -- it might help someone else in future.